# Specify max and min for Random.nextInt()?

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: generating random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

I want to generate a random int in a logical range. So, say for example, I'm writing a program to "roll" a dice with a specified number of sides.

```
public int rollDice() {
     Random generator = new Random();
     return generator.nextInt(sides);
}
```

Now the problem becomes that this will return values between sides and zero, *inclusive*, which makes no sense because most dice go from 1 to 6, 9, etc. So how can I specify that nextInt should work between 1 and the number of sides?

Comment: Can you just use return generator.nextInt(sides-1)+1?

Comment: Please check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range). Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think you mean generator.nextInt(sides)+1

Comment: Yeah, my bad :) I always forget that inclusive in this case means 0 <= i < sides

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To generate a random int value (uniform distribution) between *from* and *to* (inclusive) use:

```
from + rndGenerator.nextInt(to - from + 1)
```

In your case (1..sides):

```
1 + rndGenerator.nextInt(sides)
```